# Two public groups are in Same Queue i have to restrict one group to see case record

Tags: workflow, queue

I have added two different public groups ( for example Group-1 & Group-2 ) in one QUEUE..
i am assigning case to this QUEUE using case assignment rule..in this scenario both
Group-1,Group-2 users can access this case..

Here My Requirement is i have  to restrict one Group to see case record based on criteria means only one Group can have access another wont access..

Here two public groups are in Same Queue.

Can i do this using a work flow Rule or else How can i achieve this??

Comment: Is there any reason to assign multiple groups in one queue? Do you always want that case is assigned to only one group?

Comment: Case should be always assigned to only one group based on some conditions. These 2 groups include 2 different types of users. Restricted and Unrestricted.

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello anjalee :)

You can create another Queue containing just the first group, and modify your assignment rules to get assign cases to the new Queue.

Hope it could helps you.

Regards

Comment: Hi Amer, I actually need to know if there is a way to do this using only one queue. Thanks :)